# How to turn off "page" event seletively

Tags: jqpagination

I am using the jqPagination from Ben Everard. It's a nice plugin and saved me coding pagination logic.

I have a search and a button ,when  a user enters a value and clicks the button I do Ajax search and the following to update the paginator:

```
$('#search-by-quote-id-paginator').jqPagination('option', 'current_page', 1);

$('#search-by-quote-id-paginator').jqPagination('option', 'max_page', totalpages);
```

(This required because on the screen the paginator may be showing the "page x of xxx". Since the user has launched a new search by entering in the search box and pressed the button. )

However each of those lines  triggers a page: event and my page: function gets executed. How can I turn off triggering of the "page:" event selectively , I want it to happen only on the following line:

```
$('#search-by-quote-id-paginator').jqPagination('option', 'current_page', 1);
```

so I want to turn it off for the following line

```
$('#search-by-quote-id-paginator').jqPagination('option', 'max_page', totalpages);
```

Thanks !

Harinder

Comment: Hi Harinder... this is a good question, never thought people would want to turn ofd the `paged` callback, I'll consider adding something to sort this out. In the meantime you could reference a boolean variable within the `paged()` callback of which you could drop out of the function early, that'd be the best bet in the short term.

Comment: Added a github issue for this https://github.com/beneverard/jqPagination/issues/19

Answer (score 3):

This issue has now been fixed in version 1.3 of the plugin.

You can now set multiple options with one call to the `option` function, this includes the option to not trigger the `paged()` callback:

```
$(".pagination").jqPagination("option", {
    max_page : 1,
    current_page : 50,
    trigger : false
});
```

Comment: Hi Ben,  
---

Getting an error "jqPagination: cannot get / set option current_page" when trying to to a 'get':  



    $('#mypaginator-id').jqPagination('option', 'current_page', undefined);  <-- old syntax
 
    $('#mypaginator-id').jqPagination('option', {'current_page': undefined}); <--- new syntax


  As per jquery.jqpagination.js code that relies on a undefined value in order to  a 'get' operation:

 base.setPage = function (page, prevent_paged) {
 
 // return current_page value if getting instead of setting
 if (page === undefined) {
   return base.options.current_page;
 }

Comment: Hi there, have you got a live example of this... or better yet can you replicate in JSBin so I can play with it. Thanks, Ben

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the update.

I have turned off the paged event for the 'max_page' by changing the following line in the function base.setMaxPage = function (max_page) in the  jquery.jqpagination.js :

// update the input element

base.updateInput();

was changed to ...

// update the input element

base.updateInput(true);

Thanks !
Harinder